# Warning: Remote host identification has changed (SSH)

Tags: ssh, windows-7, ssh-keys, known-hosts, hostkey

Most likely someone did a server update last night, because when I try to do a `rsync` (from win 7) I get the message (short version):

```
WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!  
It is possible that a host key has just been changed.  
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:x0190vsJNHPmSADGhdfefSftjnF4sB38vsoHOKU.  
Please contact your system administrator. Add correct host key in
*/home/steven/.ssh/known_hosts* to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in */home/steven/.ssh/known_hosts:1* ECDSA host key for
[some.url.com]:18720 has changed and you have requested strict checking.  
Host key verification failed.
```

After looking at similar (identical) problems on the net, I have tried:

- ssh-keygen -R  (to remove the Offending RSA key)
- Emptied my known_hosts file (it only has one line)
- Deleted known_hosts file
- Adding `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` in the ssh connection string

Then I tried to login in using ssh from command line by running `ssh server.domain.no` and I got the following message:

> The authenticity of host 'server.domain.no (255.200.211.255)' can't be
>   established. ECDSA key fingerprint is
>   SHA256:wci/jhRN+wW56QcXOqKUkkZ5hgeJSp9qn32THbsmElI.
>   Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes

Selecting yes, it seems my known hosts files was created/ updated.

> Warning: Permanently added 'server.domain.no,255.200.211.255' (ECDSA) to
>   the list of known hosts.

The problem is that no new file was generated in */home/steven/.ssh/*.

So where was this file generated?
How can I get the host key so that I may add it to my `known_hosts` file?

Any help is greatly appreciated (as I'm banging my head to the wall).

Comment: As the message said: **Please contact your system administrator.**

Comment: It also says "**IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!** Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!" ;-)

Comment: What does your `~/.ssh/config` file say?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz don't have a file called config.

Comment: Ah, shit, I just saw that `cwRsync` has it's own directory `cwRsync/home/steven/.ssh` Here I see another `known_hosts` file. But no `config` file.

Comment: @AD7six that's *port* 18720, not line...

Comment: @OliverRahner that'll teach me to skim read the question - whoops.

Comment: 18720 is the PORT number (255.200.211.255:18720) :-).   
But you are right, I was working on the wrong file. I thought `/home/steven/.ssh` was referring to `~/.ssh/`, when in fact it was referring to the folder structure found in `cwRsync`. Removing the first line from known_hosts here fixed the issue. It's now solved. Will post an answer later.